# Error column doesn't exist on custom module Odoo

Tags: python, odoo-11

I'm working on a custom module and i need to add field to res.partner model. I've add some field to this model but since 1 week, when i try to add a new one i got this error :

```
ERROR: column res_partner.my_field does not exist
```

Other field works good but not this one :

```
my_field = fields.Boolean(default=False)
```

I really don't unterstand why i have this issue. I've try to add 'contacts' dependencies to my module, it have work on my local version but not on my online verison

If somone has any idea it could be really nice

Thanks for your help

Edit
res.partner classe

```py
from odoo import api, fields, models
    
class ResPartner(models.Model):
    _inherit = 'res.partner'
    
    badge_ids = fields.One2many('mymodule.badge','client_i
    sub_ids = fields.One2many('mymodule.subs','client_id')
    #field that doesn't work
    my_field = fields.Boolean(default=False)
```

Manifest dependencies

```
'depends': ['base', 'sale', 'website', 'calendar','contacts', 'point_of_sale', 'base_automation'],
```

Comment: Try to update the `base` module, or your own module with the update button from the interface (module form)

Comment: thak for you'r answer it's working but i really don't understand why this is happening

Comment: One tip, you do not need to add so many dependencies to your manifest file. Add only the leaf modules of the dependencies tree

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Looks like a bug. Here's possible workaround:

Add 'res' to dependencies as well as 'base', then restart odoo instance.

after confirming fields updated; remove 'res' from dependencies then upgrade module.

This behavior exist on Odoo versions above 8.0

Comment: thanks @kholioeg this was useful to install, but i think it may have interfered with the uninstall, now when i uninstall it the columns may not have been deleted, is this possible?

Answer (score 5):

```
class Partner(models.Model):
    _inherit = "res.partner"

   my_field = fields.Boolean()
```

**Note:** Give 'base' as dependencies in manifest of your custom module.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, i've already put base as dependencies  (he is by default i think) and i've inherit the res.partner model.
I don t understand why 1 field is not working

Comment: Can you put more code here so i can give you solution.

Comment: i've had some code, updating base module looks working but i really don't understand why this is happening

Answer (score 0):

I did this to solve it

1. Comment your custom fields in xml file
2. Add depands "base", "res" in your manifest
3. Restart odoo
4. Remove "res", "base"
5. Upgrade your custom module
6. Make sure new field added in the model that you want to inherit
7. Uncomment your field in xml file
8. Upgrade your custom module

Odoo 10

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE:

A good solution for that is to inherit the model as a new model and I assume this is the official solution as well:

```
Class ResPartner(models.model):
    _name = 'res.partner'
    _inherit = 'res.partner'

    my_field = fields.Char()
```